# Unable to get code behind event to fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I have an asp.net datagrid which looks like this. I don't seem to be able to get the linkbuttons to fire.

```
   <asp:DataGrid ID="dgrdItem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dgrdItem_ItemDataBound" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EditItem" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="datagridheaderstyle"></HeaderStyle>
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="240" HeaderText="Name">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateColumn>                
          <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Comments" ItemStyle-Width="180" />
             <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Options">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <span class="infobarbutton">
                                            <td id="tdEdit" runat="server">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" CommandName="Select" Width="52" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                     </span>
                </tr>
                </table>
    </asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Options"></asp:DataGrid>
```

So the above is a stripped down version of the datagrid. Im then trying to fire the below handler which is all wired up correctly I believe.

```
Protected Sub EditItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)
    'Do Some Work here...
End Sub
```

Any advice on where I am going wrong would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing in the EditItem sub?

Comment: Just need to invoke the event. Maybe I should use Gridviews.  More info and features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the ItemCommand event. Change OnSelectedIndexChanged="EditItem" to OnEditCommand="EditItem". Or you could just remove it from markup and add a handles clause like below:

```
Protected Sub EditItem(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgrdItem.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Edit" ...

End Sub
```